# Rails array INCLUDE with only distinct words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a profanity search function which needs to find instances of an array of profane words in a long string of text.

One could do a simple `include` like:

```
if profane_words.any? {|word| self.name.downcase.include? word}
  ...
end
```

This results in a positive match if ANY of the array of profane words are present anywhere in the text.

**However**, if a word like 'hell' is considered profane, this would produce a positive match against "Hell's Angels" or "Hell's Kitchen", which is undesirable.

How can the above search be modified to only produce positive results against **distinct words or phrases**? For example, "Hell Angels" returns positive but "Hell's Angels" returns negative.

To be clear, this means we're searching for any instance of a profane word that is immediately preceded or followed by another character or apostrophe.

Comment: just do another include .... `profane_word.include? " ' "`

Comment: I don't see how that works. Doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: something like `(profane_words_array.include? your_word) && !(your_word.include? " ' ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a regex ?

```
profane_words.any? { |word| self.name.downcase.match? /#{word}(?!')/ }
```

Examples:

```
"hell's angels".match?(/hell(?!')/) # => false
"hell angel".match?(/hell(?!')/) # => true
```

`(?!')` is a negative lookup meaning it won't match if the word has a `'` right after it. If you'd like to exclude other characters you can add it to the list with pipes e.g. `(?!'|")` won't match `'`  and `"`.

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for reference.

And you could make it more performant like this:

```
self.name.downcase.match? /#{profane_words.join('|')}(?!')/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if profane_words.any? {|word| self.name.downcase.split(' ').include? word} ... end
```

Comment: This doesn't work for something like "Hell's Angels" because in that case, the issue is an apostrophe.

Comment: The word is split by the space. Hence, It should work. 

("hell's angels".split(' ').include?'Hell') => false

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a Regex containing all your profane words followed by a space or period. Bellow yo

```
 > "Hell's angels".match(/(hell|shit)[ .]/i)
 => nil

> "Hell angels".match(/(hell|shit)[ .]/i)
 => #<MatchData "Hell " 1:"Hell"> 

> "Hell's angels shit".match(/(hell|shit)[ .]/i)
 => nil
```